# How to parse HTML that is so badly structured that it does not validate?

Tags: html, xml, parsing, google-apps-script

I need to scrape some data from a website which has a very badly structured `HTML` document, so `XmlService.parse()` fails to parse it.

Here's how the "document" looks like, I have stripped off a lot of lines, but have kept the structure:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title> Funny Site </title>
</head>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> Funny Site</title>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="mainhead">
        <div class="leftHead">
        </div>  

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //$( ".overlay" ).show();
    });
</script>
<div class="contain">
    
    <div class="maine"> 
        </div>
    
    <div class="maine2">
    
<div class="footer1">           

<div class="footer2"> 
    <div class="data">
        <div class="dc">
            <div class="smalltxt">Field1</div>
            <div class="largetxt">value1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dc">
            <div class="smalltxt">Field2</div>
            <div class="largetxt">value2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dc">
            <div class="smalltxt">Field3</div>
            <div class="largetxt adjFont" id ="someId">value3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dc" >
            <div class="smalltxt">Field4</div>
            <div class="largetxt adjFont">value4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dc" style="border:none;">
            <div class="smalltxt">Field5</div>
            <div class="largetxt">value5</div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>       
</body>
</html>
```

The data I would like to grab is in the `div` with class `data`, `value1` through `value5`.

How can you at least grab the `data` class? The only thing I could come up with is to apply regular expressions, but is there a better way than that?

Comment: Regular expressions it is. Sometimes a hybrid approach: extract a part of document which is sufficiently sane to be parsed by XmlService.

Answer (score -2):

You could try implementing XSLT.

From wikipedia:

> **XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations)** is a language
>   for transforming XML documents into other XML documents, or other
>   formats such as HTML for web pages, plain text or into XSL Formatting
>   Objects.

You can use this to remove or change attributes, values, or even elements which you want to modify.

You can check out the tutorial and testers at the infamous [w3schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/)

Comment: I am not sure how this would work, because the HTML is so chaotic, it cannot be parsed into anything distantly XML, it's only the browser's mercy that allows this site to be displayed. The best I could do with it is ```split()``` and ```replace()``` parts of the string and use regex patterns to fish out the values I needed. Currently, this works, but for future reference, I wanted to explore this question and see if there is anything better than brute force string manipulation.

Comment: XSLT can do what you are trying to do. It seems like you didn't even try to check on it.